# Command binding in ContextMenu returns error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a `ListBox` with items of type *`ThemeLayer`* and I want to add context menu functionality to those items.

The `ListBox` XAML definition is as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="DataLayerList" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MaxHeight="800"
         Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=PanelGrid}" Margin="0,10,0,0" 
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionMode="Extended" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
         ItemsSource="{Binding LayersFiltered, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Add to current / new Map" 
                                  Command="{Binding AddServiceFromContext}">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="{DynamicResource AddContent16}" Width="16"
                                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The definition of *`AddServiceFromContext`* is in my ViewModel:

```
public ICommand AddServiceFromContext
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            IEnumerable<ThemeLayer> selectedThemeLayers = LayersFiltered.Where(i => i.IsSelected);
        }, true);
    }
}
```

As soon as I call and visualize the context menu the following error shows up in the XAML Binding Failures:

> ThemeLayer    AddServiceFromContext   MenuItem.Command    ICommand    AddServiceFromContext property not found on object of type ThemeLayer.

Maybe the solution for this issue is trivial and means I have to add a property to my *`ThemeLayer`* definition, but how would that look, and is this the right solution?

Comment: In which class is AddServiceFromContext placed?

Comment: Inside of the base class of the ViewModel ``` internal class DockpanePublicDataViewModel : DockPane```

Comment: @TomGeo The `DockpanePublicDataViewModel` is the data context of the `DataLayerList` `ListBox`? So it also exposes the `LayersFiltered` collection?

Comment: Yes, DockpanePublicDataViewModel is the data context of the ListBox and it exposes also LayersFiltered as List<ThemeLayer>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddServiceFromContext` command is defined in the view model that also exposes the `LayersFiltered` collection. However, a `ListBoxItem` inside a `ListBox` gets its `DataContext` set to the corresponding data item in the items source, which is `LayersFiltered`. That is what the error is telling you, the data context is an item of type `ThemeLayer` and it does not expose a property `AddServiceFromContext`.

What you have to do is access the data context of the `ListBox` (or any other parent that shares this data context), which is `DockpanePublicDataViewModel` and contains the `AddServiceFromContext` command. The problem is that a simple `RelativeSource` binding to find parent elements will not work, as the context menu is not part of the same visual tree as the `ListBox`.

There is a workaround that you can use in cases like this, where the data context is inaccessible. Create a binding proxy type that indirectly provides a data context as a resource. For more information how this works, you can refer to [this blog post by Thomas Levesque](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
   protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
   {
      return new BindingProxy();
   }

   public object Data
   {
      get => GetValue(DataProperty);
      set => SetValue(DataProperty, value);
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(Data), typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy));
}
```

Create an instance of the binding proxy in the `ListBox` resources or anywhere else, where you can bind the target data context via the `Data` property.

```
<ListBox.Resources>
   <local:BindingProxy x:Key="DataLayerListBindingProxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

Then you can bind the command using the binding proxy as `Source`.

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Add to current / new Map" 
                      Command="{Binding Data.AddServiceFromContext, Source={StaticResource DataLayerListBindingProxy}}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource AddContent16}" Width="16"
                           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be due to the fact that the `AddServiceFromContext` command is defined in the viewModel and not in the class used to define the `LayersFiltered` list

There can be 2 solutions:

1. Define the command into the `LayersFiltered` class
2. use relative context, something like

> `{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource Mode = FindAncestor, AncestorType = {x: Type UserControl}}, Path = DataContext.AddServiceFromContext}`

Comment: LayersFiltered is as well defined in the ViewModel.

Comment: Ok, but where is defined the command `AddServiceFromContext` ? Because when you bind the command into your ListBox field, the code will try to find an object called `AddServiceFromContext` into each item contained in the ItemSource. If the `AddServiceFromContext` is defined into the view model and not into the class of items contained into the `LayersFiltered` the code rise an error!
Unless you define a RelativeSource in your binding (solution 2), this provide to the code with the information of where to find the command.

Comment: NOTE: i suggest you to try the solution number 2, seems to fit well to your use case.
Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 some microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`AddServiceFromContext` is not a member of the `DataContext` of the `MenuItem`. If it is defined in the view model, you could bind the `Tag` property of the `ListBoxItem` to the view model and then bind the `Command` to the `PlacementTarget` of the parent `ContextMenu`:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding DataContext,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add to current / new Map" 
                          Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.AddServiceFromContext, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        ...
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```